# Affine variety defined by pairs of expressions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I am interested in affine varieties of a particular form, and curious whether they have been studied before. (My interest is primarily in the 1-dimensional case, but the discussion below allows for general dimension $n$.) If $g$ is an $n$-variate polynomial over a field ${\mathbb F}$, then define $V(g) = \{x \in {\mathbb F}^n : g(x)=0\}$.

Let $S=\{f_1, \ldots, f_\ell\}$ be a set of polynomials in $n$ variables over a field ${\mathbb F}$. The set of points on which *some* polynomial in $S$ vanishes is given by $V(\prod_i f_i)$. I want to consider instead the set of points on which some *pair* of (distinct) polynomials are *equal*, i.e., $V(\prod_{i \neq j} (f_i-f_j))$. Is there a name for something like this?